# Calculating a timewindow with Python datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'd like to query my DB for all records posted on a particular day (e.g. today between 00:00 and 23:59:59) given a datetime.datetime timestamp such as datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 21, 17, 59, 43, 85335).

What's the best method to calculate the start and end datetime.datetime instances, please? I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
>>> timestamp = datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 21, 17, 59, 43, 85335)
>>> # do something with timestamp to get start_date and end_date 
>>> start_date
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> end_date
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 21, 23, 59, 59, 0)
```

Thanks, HC

Comment: Does your DB offer functions converting a datetime into a DATE? Then you can select `DATE(column) = '2010-12-21'`

Answer (score 3):

Ah, found what I want. I struggle with datetime every time.

```
>>> timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> timestamp
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 21, 18, 31, 37, 900795)
>>> timestamp.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 21, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just calculating a day, then what you have is fine. Just use the day and then put the hour as 0:00 and 23:59 respectively.

If you want to get the start and end times of a month, that gets a lot more complicated since months have different days. For something like that you could use this module

http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil

Answer (score 0):

timedelta sounds just like what you need.

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

from datetime import datetime, date

date.today() - timedelta(days=7)

Will give you 7 days from today.